# Using ZeroMQ with angular

Tags: angular, zeromq

I'm working on a project that consists of several applications that communicate with each other via ZMQ messages. I'm interested in using angular to develop a web front end that can interact with one of the existing processes. It would be convenient if I could just use ZMQ messages for this.

Googling for examples has been disappointing.

Is this something that's so trivial that no-one bothers explaining how to do it?

Or, conversely, is it so painful that any alternative is preferable?

Comment: Your Angular app runs in the browser. You cannot use ZeroMQ from the browser because you cannot create plain TCP/IP sockets in the browser.

Comment: @rveed Thanks - I'm less naive about Angular than I was a month ago. Currently I've got a Flask server that handles HTTP traffic from Angular and 0MQ traffic from the rest of the processing chain.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some progress - I found angular documentation describing how to add npm packages. The shell command:

```
ng add zeromq
```

succeeded, although this warning was generated

```
Package "zeromq" was found but does not support schematics.
```

I added `import * as zmq from 'zeromq';` to my .service.ts, and the compiler didn't complain. We'll see what happens when I try to use any of the zmq functions.

To continue, once I did try to do anything with the zmq functions I ran into some substantial hurdles. I posted a separate question about build problems related to polyfills (["angular polyfill fallback for path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76157982/angular-polyfill-fallback-for-path)) with an answer detailing the bandaid I eventually used. Once I actually tried running, I immediately ran into a new problem - not being able to resolve an environment variable. Like the polyfill issue, this seems to stem from the overhaul of `webpack`. I tried downgrading the version of webpack, but only managed to make the project unuseable.

So, for now, I'm exploring other technologies.