# angular polyfill fallback for path

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm going down the rabbit-hole of trying to add ZeroMQ support for an Angular application. I've been able to use `npm` to install `zeromq.js`. However, when I try to do a build, I get various errors about `webpack` and polyfills. The text describing a remedy is, for example:

```
./node_modules/@aminya/node-gyp-build/index.js:2:11-26 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '<...>/node_modules/@aminya/node-gyp-build'

    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

My question is, where should I be adding one of the other of these recommended JSON entries? I tried adding an entry to`package.json` in `@aminya/node-gyp-build` without improving things.

On the off chance that I really did need a `path` implentation, I installed `path-browserify`, and modified the top-level `tsconfig.json` (telling it about `path-browserify`), and `angular.json` (adding an `allowedCommonJsDependencies` list that includes "path-browserify"). This also didn't clear up the build errors.

What should I actually be modifying?

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time looking at related questions on SO, I did find an approach that got rid of the compilation errors. In the `package.json` file at the root of my angular project, I added the following entry:

```
  "browser" : {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

There are other problems for me to chase down with the logic in my code, so I don't know if I actually need the "browserify" flavors of any of those modules. Crossing my fingers that I don't.

Comment: Don't work for me